# fly through the air

Tags: figurative-language

If we say a pole vaulter "flies through the air," are we using the phrase literally or figuratively?

> The pole vaulter flew through the air.

Comment: In contrast, "He floats" (figuratively) "through the air with the greatest of ease / That daring young man on the flying trapeze."

Comment: People don't fly. So....

Comment: Never heard of airplanes, hang gliders, human cannonballs? What level of contraption is sufficient for it to be called flight?

Answer (score 0):

*Figurative*.  The literal meaning of "fly" is the action of birds, airplanes etc.  They use power and aerodynamics and so can maintain a controlled altitude.

If you asked a pole-vaulter "can you fly" I expect their answer would be "no".

It has a figurative meaning, that is common enough to be listed in many dictionaries, of "move rapidly through the air in an uncontrolled manner"

Comment: Can't they fly like a projectile?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: They can fly like a projectile.  That is a figurative sense of "fly".